# HTML and CSS table/grid design

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table, css-grid

I was trying to design table below. I tried to use a HTML table but I couldn't get the box shadow to apply properly as I had to round the corners of the first and last td cells and not the tr (as it doesn't support a border radius) but then applying a box shadow to the row didn't go round the curved edges, rather it stayed square.

I also tried display:grid & flex, however, I could find a way to get the box-shadow/border-radius and centre align the text within columns, it was a trade off.

So any advice would be much appreciated.

This is what I was trying to convert to HTML and CSS.

[image]

This is the react code is use to render the HTML for the table:

```
<div className="policy-container">
        <div className="policy-table">
            <div className="headings">
                <span className="heading">Name</span>
                <span className="heading">Last Updated</span>
                <span className="heading">Actions</span>
            </div>

            {data.map((row, ri) => (
                <div key={ri} className="policy">
                    <span>{row.name}</span>
                    <span>{row.lastUpdated.format("Do MMM YYYY")}</span>
                    <span>
                        <a href={row.link}>view</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this, using flex:

```css
body {
  background-color: #eefbfb;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.policy-table {
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.headings, .policy {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.heading {
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.policy {
  border-radius: 2em;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px grey;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px grey;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px grey;
}

span {
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}
```

```html
<div class="policy-container">
  <div class="policy-table">
    <div class="headings">
      <span class="heading">Name</span>
      <span class="heading">Last Updated</span>
      <span class="heading">Actions</span>
    </div>

    <div class="policy">
      <span>Name</span>
      <span>DD MM YY</span>
      <span>
        <a href={row.link}>view</a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="policy">
      <span>Name</span>
      <span>DD MM YY</span>
      <span>
        <a href={row.link}>view</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked well thank you. I actually had this except for the flex-basis property.

Comment: Ahh great. Yes! flex-basis is the key to getting the centring to work I think. An interesting challenge. I forgot to check if any additional browser prefixes are needed for flex-basis, I would recommend you do that for cross-browser compatibility.